# Node.js http.createServer throws TypeError: listener must be a function

Tags: koa, engine.io, primus

index.js:

```
var koa = require('koa')
  , Primus = require('primus.io')
  , http = require('http')
  , app = koa()
  , server = http.createServer(app);

var primus = new Primus(server, { transformer: 'websockets', parser: 'JSON' });

primus.on('connection', function (spark) {
  spark.send('news', { hello: 'world' });
  spark.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.listen(8080);
console.log('8080');
```

run: `node --harmony index`

and err: `throw TypeError('listener must be a function');`

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your code to do this:

`server = http.createServer(app.callback())`

Comment: Alternatively, use `app.listen(8080)` which is sugar for `http.createServer(app.callback()).listen(8080)`

Answer (score 1):

### Try: add a star '*'

```
app.get('/',function*(next){})
```